# How can I host 2 WCF self hosted services using different host names on the same machine (using the host header)

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

I'm trying to **self host** two WCF services with the following url conventions:

https://service.servicehost.com/service

https://service-branch.servicehost.com/service

And I get this error:

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not
>   register URL https://+:443/service/. Another application has already
>   registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. --->

I understand the error and I know how to work it around by changing the service's suffix, but it seems like the WCF self host doesn't support the host header feature like IIS does (since I see the + sign).

Is there any way I can make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be done for SelfHost/Http.  With Net.Tcp you would have had to use PortSharing to make this happen.

Worst case you could potentially create a [Routing Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517422(v=vs.110).aspx) that routes your requests to the correct service, where each is listening on a different port.

Also, take a look at the documentation for [HostNameComparisonMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.hostnamecomparisonmode(v=vs.110).aspx).  The docs for [basicHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx) will show you how to use it.

Comment: Adding `hostNameComparisonMode="Exact"` to the bindings configuration seems to solve this issue. Thank you.